# How can I download genePred file from UCSC?

Tags: ucsc

I need a gtf annotation file. UCSC doesn't give us a proper gtf file with distinct gene_id and transcript_id. It asked us to get a genePred file to convert to gtf.

But where can we get genePred files?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that using table browser on UCSC we could download an output with all fields. That output actually contains a GenePred file but has one extra column on the left end.

The genePred file format definition is [here](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format9).